# Dart - NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Module' has no instance getter 'String'

Tags: dart, flutter

Could some please explain what is wrong?

I try to get an item by key from HashMap:

If I do it that way:

`var stringProvider = providersHolder[String]`
 I get an error:

**NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Module' has no instance getter 'String'.**

If I do it next way:

`var stringProvider = providersHolder[providersHolder.keys.last]` 
where `providersHolder.keys.last == String`

**I get success.**

Here is a full listing:

```
class Module {
  HashMap providersHolder = new HashMap<Type, ItemCreator>();

  void addProvider<T, M extends Module>(ItemCreator<T, M> itemCreator) {
     providersHolder[T] = itemCreator;
  }
}

class Test {
    Test() {
      var module = Module();
      module.addProvider((module) => new Ticker());
      module.addProvider((module) => "hello");
      var ticketProvider = module.providersHolder[Ticker]; //success
      var stringProvider = module.providersHolder[String]; //error
    } 
}
```

Here is a watcher:

[image: watcher]

Comment: Could you provide more details? Your code works for me. I defined ItemCreator as `typedef T ItemCreator<T, M>(Module);` which may differ from yours. Is this a debugger bug?

Comment: @RichardHeap, I appreciate that you studied the matter in detail and even run the code. So far I can reproduce it only in the debugger. So, I guess your assumption that it's a debugger issue is right.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details on how ItemCreator was defined? This will help us replicate the behavior you've encountered. If you're still having the same errors, you can also run `flutter doctor -v` to check for any errors or warnings.